# What is native class in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, associations

What is `native` class in *hibernate* ? While learning about [many to many associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-m2m) in hibernate, I came across this. Like :

```
<generator class="native" />
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: Have you tried googling it? The web is full of material about this.

Comment: Also, from Chapter 5 of the same document you reference: "selects identity, sequence or hilo depending upon the capabilities of the underlying database."

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I didn't understand though I found some pages like http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/generators-in-hibernate/